# Qt slot and signal: no matching function in MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have looked at a variety of the Qt discussions for this error "no matching function for call to" and I still cannot see what is different in this case. I have successfully set up slot/signal pairs between GUI elements, but for some reason the latest set of slot/signal pairs is creating an error.

In order to allow all GUI elements to update the status bar on the main window I have created a signal in each panel as shown here

```
class PanelA : public QWidget
{
  ...
  public signals:
     void UpdateStatusBar(std::string);
  ...
}
```

Then in MainWindow there is a slot

```
//from MainWindow.h
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  private slots:
     void ReceiveStatus(std::string);
}

//from MainWindow.cpp
void MainWindow::ReceiveStatus(std::string s)
{
  //I can provide other controls, filters, etc.
  //but currently there are none
  ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("System status: "+s));
}
```

And finally, in the MainWindow constructor I have several signals already and I have added one new connect line for each GUI element.

```
connect(ui->panelA, &PanelA::SelectionChanged, ui->panelB, &PanelB::UpdateSelection);
//this one works
connect(ui->panelA, &PanelA::UpdateStatusBar, ui, &MainWindow::ReceiveStatus);
//this one generates an error there is one status bar connection for each
```

So, as far as I can tell the syntax is right. both ui->panelA and ui are pointers. I don't know why one is correct and the other is wrong. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably should be:

```
connect(ui->panelA, &PanelA::UpdateStatusBar, this, &MainWindow::ReceiveStatus);
```

The `ui` object isn't a MainWindow, but `this` will be.

Comment: Thank you. Silly of me to miss that. You are right. Ui::MainWindow *ui is not the same as the MainWindow class where the method is defined.